# Leaflet with R: Number formatting and thousands separator in label

Tags: r, leaflet, label

So i'm trying to include some numeric figures in my label but am struggling to get it in the correct accounting format so that it is consistent with the legend. I have no trouble producing the labels without any numeric formatting, so any help in achieving the desired thousands separator would be brilliant.

```
library(geojson)
library(geojsonio)
library(leaflet)
library(sf)

url <- "http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/us-states.js"
doc <- readLines(url)
doc2 <- gsub("var statesData = ", "", doc)
write(doc2, file = "tempgeo.json")
states <- geojson_read("tempgeo.json", what = "sp")

bins <- c(0, 10000, 20000, 50000, 100000, 200000, 500000, 1000000, Inf)
pal <- colorBin("YlOrRd", domain = states$density, bins = bins)

states$density <- states$density*1000

c <- leaflet(states) %>%
  setView(-96, 37.8, 4) %>%
  addProviderTiles("MapBox", options = providerTileOptions(
    id = "mapbox.light",
    accessToken = Sys.getenv('MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN')))


labels <- sprintf(
  "<strong>%s</strong><br/>%g",
  states$name, states$density
) %>% lapply(htmltools::HTML)



c <- c %>% addPolygons(
  fillColor = ~pal(density),
  weight = 2,
  opacity = 1,
  color = "white",
  dashArray = "3",
  fillOpacity = 0.7,
  highlight = highlightOptions(
    weight = 5,
    color = "#666",
    dashArray = "",
    fillOpacity = 0.7,
    bringToFront = TRUE),
  label = labels,
  labelOptions = labelOptions(
    style = list("font-weight" = "normal", padding = "3px 8px"),
    textsize = "15px",
    direction = "auto")) %>%
  addLegend(pal = pal, values = ~density, opacity = 0.7, title = NULL,
            position = "bottomright")
c
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You can convert the label to a string, and use `prettyNum` to format it with commas.

```
labels <- sprintf(
  "<strong>%s</strong><br/>%s",
  states$name, prettyNum(states$density, big.mark = ",")
) %>% lapply(htmltools::HTML)
```

Comment: Is there a way to have two decimal point outputs? I am working with a currency label, applied your answer and everything works but only get 1 value after the decimal point.